# Continuity from left of a strictly increasing function and Heine's definition

Tags: calculus, measure-theory, continuity

I am learning measure theory and I am looking at the following proposition:

Let $h:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $h$ is *strictly increasing* function. If $t_n \to t_0^-$ (from left) is arbitrary *increasing* sequence and $\lim_{n \to \infty}h(t_n)=h(t_0)$ then $h$ is continues *from left* at $t_0$.

I am lost here. As far as I know in Heine's definition of continuity one should check equality of a limit for $arbitrary$ sequence, not just for increasing one.

However, $h$ is not arbitrary, $h$ is strictly increasing and we are interested in continuity *from left*.

So my question is:

Is this statement true? How can I prove or disprove it?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: If $h$ is *not* left-continuous at $t_0$, then there is some $\epsilon > 0$ and a sequence $t_n$ such that $0 < t_0 - t_n < 1/n$ but $|f(t_0) - f(t_n)| > \epsilon$. Now $t_n$ may not be increasing, but it is bounded (since it converges to $t_0$), so it contains an increasing subsequence $t_{n_k}$. That subsequence also satisfies $|f(t_0) - f(t_{n_k})| > \epsilon$, so it gives the required contradiction.

Comment: Bungo Thanks a lot for your help! Fell free to post your answer.

Comment: The solution sketched in my comment is the lazy man's approach ("there exists a subsequence") and moreover it requires already having shown that a bounded sequence contains a monotonic subsequence. I prefer the answer by Eclipse Sun since it explicitly constructs an increasing sequence. So I'll just leave mine in comment form :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general $h$ need not to be increasing.

Recall the definition. We say that $h$ is continuous at $t_0$ from the left if $\forall\epsilon>0$, $\exists\delta>0$ such that $\forall x\in(t_0-\delta,t_0)$ we have $|f(x)-f(t_0)|<\epsilon$.

Suppose $h$ is NOT continuous at $t_0$ from the left. Then $\exists\epsilon>0$, $\forall\delta>0$, $\exists x\in(t_0-\delta,t_0)$ but $|f(x)-f(t_0)|>\epsilon$.

For $\delta=1$, we call such $x$ as $t_1$.
For $\delta=\min\{1/2,t_0-t_1\}$, we call such $x$ as $t_2$.
...
For $\delta=\min\{1/n,t_0-t_{n-1}\}$, we call such $x$ as $t_n$...

Then $t_n\uparrow t_0$, but $|h(t_n)-h(t_0)|>\epsilon$ for all $n$. Thus, $h(t_n)\not\to h(t_0)$. Contradiction.